# REGEX specification for .NET to capture text with double carets

Tags: regex

I was wondering if someone can help with this. I trying to come up with an appropriate RegEx to capture the following strings (Conditional Expression Ternary operators) within a market research (e.g., ConfirmIT) XML file to be excluded from language translation.

Strings to be captured - examples:

```
^f('field1').get()^
^punchLastQAnswered(CurrentForm())^
```

RegEX:

```
\^f[\w\W]*\^
\^[a-zA-Z]{1}\(*\)\^
```

The trouble is when there are two such strings on the same line, both are being captured together including the word "and" in between.

```
^f('field1').get()^ and ^f('field2').get()^
```

How do I change the RegEx to do for each individual string only? Is there a way to specific string boundary? I tired `"/b"` but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
\^.+?\^(?=\s|$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qG3fZ5/2)